# How do i turn a list with multiple values into a dictionary with only 2 values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list called country_population, looking like this:

```
[
  'Guam',
  {'total_population': {'date': '2013-01-01', 'population': 163943}},
  'Central%20African%20Republic',
  {'total_population': {'date': '2013-01-01', 'population': 4665025}}
]
```

I've tried to do `dict(country_population)`

which gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required
```

I understand that my list has 4 values, but how do i turn it into a dictionary with only 2 values?
I want a result that looks this:

```
country_population = {'Guam' : '163943, 'Central%20African%20Republic' : 
'4665025' }
```

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in a dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
my_list = ['Guam', {'total_population': {'date': '2013-01-01', 'population': 163943}}, 'Central%20African%20Republic', {'total_population': {'date': '2013-01-01', 'population': 4665025}}]
# dictionary to store new results
result = {}

for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2):
    result[my_list[i]] = my_list[i+1]['total_population']['population']

print(result)
```

Result:

```
{'Central%20African%20Republic': 4665025, 'Guam': 163943}
```

And for above code using `dictionary comprehension`, you can try as:

```
result = {my_list[i] : my_list[i+1]['total_population']['population'] 
                                                for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dict()` and `zip`

**Demo:**

```
country_population = ['Guam', {'total_population': {'date': '2013-01-01', 'population': 163943}}, 'Central%20African%20Republic', {'total_population': {'date': '2013-01-01', 'population': 4665025}}]
print(dict((i[0], i[1]['total_population']["population"])for i in zip(country_population[0::2], country_population[1::2])))
```

**Output:**

```
{'Central%20African%20Republic': 4665025, 'Guam': 163943}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result that you described is invalid because it has multiple keys called `Name` and `Population`. I think what you want is `Name` to be the key and `Population` to be the value, which you can do by jumping through the list in increments of two and adding each pair to a dict.

```
d=dict()
for i in range(len(country_population)/2):
    d[country_population[2*i]] = 
        country_population[2*i+1]['total_population']['population']
```

The result of `d['Guam']` will be 163943.